# forced update app with AlertController

Tags: ios, swift, url, alert, uialertcontroller

I make for my application forced update but when I go back without updating the application AlertController disappears as it can be fixed

If you know other options to make a forced update, then write

thanks for the help

```
   func version(){

    if let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
        self.labelVersion = version
        dowloand()
    }

}

func dowloand(){
...JSON request

    if labelVersion == JsonVersion{
        showTopLevelAlert()
    } else {

    }
}


func showTopLevelAlert() {
    let alertController = UIAlertController (title: "Доступно обновление", message: "Для продолжения работы с приложением необходимо обновиться.", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let Update = UIAlertAction(title: "Обновить", style: .default, handler:{(action) in

        let url = URL(string: "http://appstore.com/")!
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }

    })


    alertController.addAction(Update)



    let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
    alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()

    alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your application's version in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Then send notification like:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AppUpdateRequired"), object: nil)
```

And catch this notification in your view controller to show the alert with update prompt.

Or more dynamic way would be using this extension:

```
extension UIApplication {
  class func topViewController(base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
        let moreNavigationController = tab.moreNavigationController

        if let top = moreNavigationController.topViewController where top.view.window != nil {
            return topViewController(top)
        } else if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(presented)
    }
    return base
  }
}
```

To get the top view controller and show your alert with prompting to update.

Comment: Thanks, everything works fine, but the second is faster